# run databrick workspace from .net console app

Tags: c#, .net, databricks, azure-databricks

I've got a databricks workspace that runs some python scripts to query some data. Is there a way to trigger this script in the workspace from the console app and have it output the data to azure blob storage? If so, can i pass parameters to the workspace from my app to use in the query?

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately, you cannot run Databricks workspace from the .net console app.

I would suggest you to provide feedback on the same:

https://databricks.com/feedback

All of the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.

---

If you are interested in deploying your app to Databricks, make sure your app is .NET Standard compatible and that you use .NET Core compiler to compile your app.

This [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/spark/tutorials/databricks-deployment) teaches you how to deploy your app to the cloud through Azure Databricks, an Apache Spark-based analytics platform with one-click setup, streamlined workflows, and interactive workspace that enables collaboration.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this via REST API. This could be done via [Jobs API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#), either by:

1. Creating the job for your existing notebooks or Python scripts, and then triggering the job via [Run now command](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#run-now)
2. Using [Runs Submit](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#runs-submit) call - in this case you won't need to create a job, but it looks like that you can't pass parameters to a job (that's quite strange, maybe the documentation is missing)

to use REST API you need to authenticate, but this is [well described in the documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/authentication.html)